# How do I write only so many lines from a read file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv that I am reading from and about 10-15 lines contain what the search parameters are but I only want to write a new file showing just 3 of them and cannot figure out how to do that.

`with open('events.csv', 'r', encoding = 'latin-1') as read_file, open('today.txt', 'w', encoding='latin-1') as write_file:
        reader = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=',')
        writer = csv.writer(write_file)
        for row in reader:
            if day in row[0]:
                writer.writerow(row)`

Comment: Then hire a developer. Or, better yet, include the code you've written so far and its errors, and we'll help you through it.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: only code I have will write all the lines that match the search criteria, to a new file.  I get no error as I don't know how to get it to just print a few lines.  I put the code I have above.

Comment: Have you tried count to 3 then breaking the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add counter:

```
n = 0
with open('events.csv', 'r', encoding = 'latin-1') as read_file, open('today.txt', 'w', encoding='latin-1') as write_file:
            reader = csv.reader(read_file, delimiter=',')
            writer = csv.writer(write_file)
            for row in reader:
                if day in row[0] and n < 3:
                    writer.writerow(row)
                    n += 1
                elif n >= 3:
                    break
```